# Necesito un random en html para unas preguntas

Tags: php, html

La cuestión es que me código es en HTML y tengo como cien preguntas pero solo quiero que me aparezca diez, las preguntas tienen Radiobutton, mi primer código es ese htmml y valido en php en un segundo codigo

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. HTML como tal no tiene forma de generar elementos aletoriamente. Para generar elementos aletoriamente tendrás que generarlos mediante PHP o mediante JavaScript. En tu caso te interesaría más que se generase desde PHP ya que si lo creases desde JS las preguntas/respuestas serían visibles desde por el cliente. ¿Tienes algo de código empezado? Si es así, por favor, edita la pregunta y añade lo que tengas empezado para tener un punto de partida donde la gente te pueda ayudar más fácilmente.

Comment: Que llevas hecho? Las preguntas amplias y basadas en opiniones terminan cerradas

Answer (score -1):

El siguiente código resuelve tu problema, de ay ya lo puedes aplicar como veas:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        Pregunta 1:
        <p id="p1"></p>
        Pregunta 2:
        <div id="p2"></div>
        <script>
            preguntas=["primera", "segunda", "tercera"];
            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = preguntas[(Math.random()*3).toFixed()];
            document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = preguntas[(Math.random()*3).toFixed()];
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Este código tiene dos problemas, el primero, si pruebas a ejecutarlo varias veces vas a ver como a veces algunas preguntas salen como `undefined`. Eso se podría resolver ajustando la generación del número aleatorio para que el valor obtenido no sobrepasase el tamaño del array de preguntas. El otro problema es que, si se hace un sitio de preguntas y respuestas donde la información (array preguntas) se encuentra en el JS, un usuario espabilado podría ver los atos de todas las preguntas. Esto podría dar igual para un ejercicio, pero en un caso real no sería buena idea.